# How to make only one field to be editable?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I'm in the process of learning Blazor Server. Thus far, everything appears to be functioning correctly, but I've encountered an issue where, upon attempting to edit a single item from a list, the EditForm is appearing for all the other items as well. Can you provide guidance on resolving this problem? I appreciate your assistance in advance.

```
@if(Wishes is not null)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (Wish item in Wishes)
        {
            <li>
                <span>
                    @if (IsEdit && _EditWish is not null)
                    {
                        <EditForm Model="@_EditWish">
                            <InputNumber @bind-Value="_EditWish.Id" hidden/>
                            <InputText @bind-Value="_EditWish.Title" />
                            <button @onclick="UpdateWish" class="btn-save">Save</button>
                        </EditForm>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @item.Title
                    }
                </span>
            </li>

        }
    </ul>
}

@code {
    private List<Wish> Wishes = new() { new Wish { Id = 1, Title = "Wish One" }, new Wish { Id = 2, Title = "Wish Two" } };
    private bool IsEdit{ get; set; }
    private Wish _EditWish { get; set; } = new Wish();

    private async Task UpdateWish()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Wish? findWish = Wishes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _EditWish.Id);
            if (findWish is not null)
            {
                findWish.Title = _EditWish.Title;
            }
            IsEdit = false;
        });
    }

    private async Task EditWish(int id)
    {
        IsEdit = true;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Wish? findWish = Wishes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            if (findWish is not null)
            {
                _EditWish.Id = findWish.Id;
                _EditWish.Title = findWish.Title;
            }
        });
    }
.....
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to explain your problem better.  The code is doing exactly what you've asked it to, display an edit for form all the items in `Wishes`, but that is clearly not what you want.  How do you select the one you want to edit?